# iOS Test Flight Internal Beta Testing - adding a second build?

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

I'm trying to use Apple's new TestFlight beta testing program and I am getting hung up on adding a second build.

I began the whole process by creating a new app version for submission (1.4). It now sits in the Prepare For Submission state.

My first prerelease build, uploaded through xcode, was version 1.4. I was able to add testers and distribute without any problems. Cool.

Now I am trying to add a second beta - When I first tried, I was denied because of a 'redundant binary upload' -- I was using the same bundle version number. So I incremented it to 1.4.1 and added that build.

Now that the build is added, however, I am unable to add any testers to this second upload. I keep seeing this:

[image]

However, when I go to the builds page, I see the testers I've already added!

Why can i not distribute this second version???

Comment: Are you sure the second version is not already distributed to them?

Comment: Ya I am one of the testers and Its not showing up in my TestFlight app, nor did I get an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the "Bundle Version" (aka the Build version) in your info.plist.  Alternatively, you can go to your project Target, select the General tab, and update the "Build" there.  Updating either location will update both locations.

Then the steps are the same as when you uploaded your first build for beta.  I just went through this process and it went off without a hitch.